# Calculating kWh from time series of kW

Tags: electricity, power, statistics

I have a time series of kW where each sample is measured at regular intervals (10 seconds). Could anyone explain to me how could I calculate the total power consumed (kWh) over an hour?

Thanks

Comment: The total kWh is $\frac{1}{360}\sum_{n=1}^{360}p_n$, where the $p_n$ are the kW power measurements for each 10 second increment (assuming you are looking at a 1-hour interval).

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus would this formula work if this is continuous data?

Comment: What does "continuous data" mean? In your question you said that it is being sampled at 10-second intervals, which is discrete, not continuous.

Comment: It's fine, don't worry about wording. As another example, if you sample with 0.5-second measurements, and you measure for 469 seconds (ie a total of 938 measurements), then you have $E=\frac{0.5}{3600}\sum_{n=1}^{938}p_n$.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I think it would really be better if you post your answer as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: Incidentally, this question seems to me to be about the very basics of numerical integration. I don't think it's off topic (although I could see that being debatable), but I have a vague feeling it might be a duplicate of something we already have. Unfortunately I can't find a specific question it would be a duplicate of.

Comment: @DavidZ: Yeah I guess, but I figured this was simple enough to be written in a comment and still be useful to the OP.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus well, what makes something an answer vs. a comment is not whether it's simple or not. It's a matter of whether it answers the question or not. There are many times when a valid answer is simple enough to be written in a comment and yet should still be posted as an answer. Another good rule of thumb: comments are temporary. Anything that is useful in the long term should be either edited into the question or posted as an answer. (BTW I will come back and clean up the comments here after the discussion is over.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you have a list of datapoints $p_n$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,...,N\}$ sampled with timestep $\Delta t$, the integrated total $E$ is
$$E=\Delta t\sum_{n=1}^{N}p_n.$$

For example, with data spaced 10 seconds apart, $\Delta t$ becomes $\frac{10\text{ sec}}{3600\text{ sec/hour}}\approx 0.0028$ hours. If you take 20 measurements (ie, 200 seconds recording), the integrated power in kWh becomes
$$E=\frac{1}{360\text{ samples/hour}}\sum_{n=1}^{20}p_n$$
where $p_n$ are the instantaneous powers in kW.

This is an example of numerical integration using a [Riemann Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Sum).

Comment: My edit message got squashed. It was: it's good numerical practice to use integer ratios when possible, rather than introducing floating-point approximations like 0.0027778

Comment: @rob: Seems fine, although the "samples" unit seems sort of redundant.

Comment: So can we consider them to be for 10 seconds interval, the sum of all datapoints (Watt points) multiplied by 10/3600 giving the wh, and then the wh divided by 1000 giving the kwh?